# Why compareTo should not return Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube. There is a [rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2167) against java language:

> It is the sign, rather than the magnitude of the value returned from
> compareTo that matters. Returning Integer.MIN_VALUE does not convey a
> higher degree of inequality, and doing so can cause errors because the
> return value of compareTo is sometimes inversed, with the expectation
> that negative values become positive. However, inversing
> Integer.MIN_VALUE yields Integer.MIN_VALUE rather than
> Integer.MAX_VALUE.

The problem is SonarQube consider this a bug, not code smell. Under what circumstances would this cause an error?

Can anyone give a example ?

Comment: The message is pretty clear here: "the return value of compareTo is sometimes inversed, with the expectation that negative values become positive". What part of this do you not understand?

Comment: I am not English speaker, "However, inversing Integer.MIN_VALUE yields Integer.MIN_VALUE rather than Integer.MAX_VALUE" is not that obvious for me, but  `System.out.println(-b); // -2147483648` is

Comment: @WestFarmer Now that you know that, watch out for similar cases! :-) The same is true for `Long.MIN_VALUE`, etc in Java. You can also run into the same problem with other languages (like C) which have integers with a fixed number of bits, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is here：

```
Integer a = -1;
Integer b = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

System.out.println(b); // -2147483648
System.out.println(-b); // -2147483648

System.out.println(a); // -1
System.out.println(-a); // 1
```

If you want to use the result of compareTo to judge, for example:

```
Integer a = x.compareTo(y)


if(-a > 0) {
    
    //do something

}
```

If the return value of `compareTo` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then the value of `-a` is equal to the value of `a` both are `-2147483648`, so the result is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you do return `MIN_VALUE`:

```
class PossiblyBadlyWrittenClass implements Comparable<PossiblyBadlyWrittenClass> {
    @NotNull private final int value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull PossiblyBadlyWrittenClass o) {
        if (value > o.value) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else if (value < o.value) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // constructor, and other boilerplate...
}
```

Now someone else comes along and uses this `PossiblyBadlyWrittenClass` in their class. They want their class' natural order to be the *reverse* order of how `PossiblyBadlyWrittenClass` is ordered.

One way someone would do this, is to negate whatever your implementation of `compareTo` returns. They'd think that by using `+`, if your `compareTo` returns a positive numbers, then theirs would return a negative number, and vice versa.

```
class SomethingElse implements Comparable<SomethingElse> {
    @NotNull private final PossiblyBadlyWrittenClass foo;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull SomethingElse o) {
        return -foo.compareTo(o.foo);
    }

    // ...
}
```

But this is not the case! When your `compareTo` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (a negative number), applying the unary `-` operator to it gives you `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again, because of overflow.

`MIN_VALUE` is `-2147483648`. Mathematically, if you negate that, you get `2147483648`. But `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`, just 1 smaller. Therefore, the mathematically correct result cannot be represented as an `int`. The value "wraps around" to the negatives.

So now their `compareTo` has a bug.

Of course, you might argue that this is that person's fault as they did not consider this edge case. And that they should have written it like this instead:

```
return o.foo.compareTo(foo);
```

But then people using *that* code will need to be careful too. It would be much easier if you never returned `MIN_VALUE` in the first place, so nobody would need to worry about this edge case.